# Proofs of abelian group axioms for elliptic curve over finite fields + tangent-chord group law

Tags: abelian-groups, elliptic-curves

I'm looking for the proofs of the abelian group axioms for elliptic curve over finite fields (e.g. integers mod p) with the tangent-chord group law (i.e. the "standard" group law for elliptic curves) as the group operation:

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Identity element
4. Inverse element
5. Commutativity

References to papers or books are fine, as well as multiple proofs per axiom. I have done some research and have found some myself, but I've come up with nothing especially regarding closure.

I'm a physicist by training, so it might entirely be possible that I overlooked some well-known connections.

Answer (score 0):

One very popular textbook in the field is https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387094939 by Silverman. Section III.2 contains proofs of closure, identity, commutativity and inverse in Proposition 2.2. Associativity is only sortof proved there, but there are references to different approaches to the proof there.

Comment: Proposition 2.2 says that the tangent-chord group law makes an elliptic curve into an abelian group. The proof states that "all of this is easy except for the associativity" and regarding the closure it says (nearly direct quote) "Obvious from the group law, or look at the graph where the line hits the curve". I agree that this is intuitive for an infinite field like the real numbers, but I don't understand how that should work for a finite field at all. It's necessary to prove that the line hits the curve only in the points contained in the finite field - that's closure, right?

Comment: After another hour of research, I think what I'm getting at regarding closure is a) Mordell's theorem says that the Q-rational points of the elliptic curve form an abelian group and b) Nagell-Lutz's theorem says that if the curve has integer coefficients, all Q-rational points have integer coordinates.

Comment: As an alternative to a): The explicit calculation for the group law R = P+Q only contains fractions and squares, so it's indeed obvious that R is rational if P and Q and the curve coefficients are rational.

Comment: Closure is part (f) saying that points defined over a field add to a point over the same field. Silverman gives an explanation based on the equation for the line, which will have the same description for all types of fields. So although the intuition it is geometric, the algebra of equations holds for all fields.

Comment: Mordell's theorem is a bit stronger, it says that the Q-rational points form a _finitely generated_ abelian group, its also a lot harder to prove than the group law in general. Nagell-Lutz is talking about torsion points with Q-coordinates only, and even then there is a weird buisness with 2 dividing the denominator sometimes even if the equation is integral. For example check out this curve https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/258/g/2 under "Torsion generators" a point is listed which isn't integral despite the equation being integral.